# Extract XML nodes using OPENXML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

[sample_xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uimE2.png) I tried to extract XML data using OPENXML in SQL, but the XML file contain prefixes such as: "pidx:CustomerID>01234", see sample_xml.

If I exclude the prefix "pidx:" it can't read data, if I include, error out:

> Msg 6603, Level 16, State 2, Line 15 XML parsing error: Reference to
>   undeclared namespace prefix: 'pidx'.

How do I do it?

Comment: can you add the xml document to the question as a text instead of image?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the complete query you are using. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Your sample XML data is invalid, please provide a valid sample and also your expected result -HTH ;).

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact, that you should **never post your code / XML as a picture**, there are some general hints:

- Your *prefixes* are binding an element to a namespace.
- This namespace must be declared!
- If your xml (as posted in the picture) is complete, it is invalid! If it is just a portion of a bigger XML you'll find the namespace's declaration somewhere above, in most cases in the root element
- `OPENXML` is outdated and should not be used any more. Better use the XML's native methods like `.value` or `.nodes()`.

### update

As requested in a comment some explanation about the need to declare a namespace. This XML is not valid:

```
<abc:test>1</abc:test>
```

Try this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=N'<abc:test>1</abc:test>';
```

You'll get this

> Msg 9459, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 XML parsing: line 1, character 10,
>   undeclared prefix

Now declare the namespace and it works

```
DECLARE @xml XML=N'<abc:test xmlns:abc="blah">1</abc:test>';
```

Such a namespace is valid for the declaring node and all elements *hierarchically below* (=*within*).

In most cases namespaces are declared within a root node

Try this

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'
<root xmlns:abc="blah">
    <abc:test>1</abc:test>
</root>
';
SELECT @xml
```

Comment: _This namespace must be declared!_ >> Perhaps you should expand on that just a little.